# htaccess redirect file.php to /file/ and non www to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have written a rule that allows my .php pages to be viewed without the file extension.

e.g.

/test-page.php is rewritten to /test-page/

I'm also redirecting non www to www. However, if I try to directly access test-page.php this doesn't get redirected - am I missing anything obvious?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. The idea was taken from [4026021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```